# How to control Switch component colors?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**Using MaterialUI v1.0:**

How can I control a specific switch component colors (inner styling)?
How can I control every switch component colors on my app?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the docs for the selection controls?

https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/selection-controls/

And have you looked into Material UI's ThemeProvider? I cant find anything in V1 about changes to the theme provider so I guess it still working but I haven't tested it

http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes